# How to identify which network interface is my application using

Tags: networking, network-adapter, wireshark

I hoped to capture network traffic -using Wireshark- via a port on which my application is running. However when I fired up Wireshark, it listed 4 network interfaces not just 1 as I expected.

So I am confused which interface is appropriate to choose to be able to capture traffic to and from my application. What is the correct way to identify the interface my application is using.

Some info:

1. None of the interfaces are wireless ones. So [this](https://superuser.com/questions/578525/which-network-connection-is-used-if-connect-using-multiple-interfaces) couldn't help
   much.
2. The only case of multiple interfaces I am aware of is VMware Virtual Ethernet Apadters but none of the adapters in this case are virtual.
3. My server is running Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This is a Wireshark question.

Comment: Some more info that's needed: what are the names of all four of the interfaces?

Comment: Can't tell right away as I can;t get immediate access got the server. But wonder how is it going to help. They all have pretty standard interface name formats.